# Syntax error - unexpected ":"

Tags: php, syntax-error, form-submit

My php script directs to a url depending on which submit button was pressed.  However, when I run the test I'm getting an error saying line 4 contains an unexpected ":" but my line 4 is my header script with the url?

I'm confused because I have other scripts similar to this and they don't give me that error.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing, might be simple, I have been caught being simple before.

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['Dish1'] == 'Dish1')
{
header(“Location: http://blahblah”.urlencode($_POST[‘uid’]));
}
else if ($_REQUEST['Dish1'] == 'Dish2')
{
header(“Location: http://blahblah2”.urlencode($_POST[‘uid’]));
}
else if ($_REQUEST['Dish1'] == 'Dish3')
{
header(“Location: http://blahblah3”.urlencode($_POST[‘uid’]));
}
etc.....
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using curly quotes.

Replace all the `“ ”` and `‘ ’` to `"` and `'` respectively.

Comment: +1 - I was just about to edit them in the question when I noticed that!

Comment: told you I could be simple sometimes think the quotes changed when I copied something over from notepad and didn't remember to change them before copying again.  Thank you all

Comment: can anyone please explain why microsoft uses these wonky characters?????

Comment: @ScottScooterWeidenkopf Probably because they think they "look nice". I mean from a purely aesthetic look, it is more obvious that `“` starts a quote and `”` ends it. This is probably one big reason why you don't use microsoft office to code in. They don't produce syntacticly correct text.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong quotes... use "" instead of “”. [Refer to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), you must use typewriter  quotes, not curly or inverted commas.

PD: Also `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' on line 15` ; )

Answer (score 0):

Replace you code with following

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST['Dish1'] == 'Dish1')
{
header("Location: http://blahblah.urlencode".($_POST['uid']));
}
else if ($_REQUEST['Dish1'] == 'Dish2')
{
header("Location: http://blahblah2".urlencode($_POST['uid']));
}
else if ($_REQUEST['Dish1'] == 'Dish3')
{
header("Location: http://blahblah3".urlencode($_POST['uid']));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it not much easier to write:

```
$lookup = array('Dish1' = > 'http://blba1', 'Dish2' = > 'http://blba2');

if( isset($lookup[$_REQUEST['Dish1']]))
  header("Location: " . $lookup[$_REQUEST['Dish1']]);
```